# How can I shrink a windows partition when \$Mft::$BITMAP is in the way?

Tags: partitioning, windows-11

Some searching on the internet leads me to believe that it has to do with NTFS but no way to move it somewhere else. Would booting from a live CD and shrinking the partition from there help?

There's about 200GB free on the partition and it has bitlocker enabled (but it's unlocked). I've already tried turning off the page file/kernel logs.

Edit: **This isnt a problem with the Mft file**, the problem is that it is in the way and there seems to be no way to move it.

Comment: a bootable solution like gparted

Comment: Disable bitlocker, then use something like AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard to resize/move the partition. I strongly advise to do one action at a time with this program though, otherwise there is a big chance it is busy for a long time, then fail without any change made. Luckily no dataloss, but waste of time, whereas doing it one action at a time seems to always work.

Comment: @cybernard I tried that and I think I did something wrong, Windows bluescreens on boot but I can still read all the data from Linux. Also the partition thinks it only has 10gb free (which is what I set in gparted) but isn't smaller.

Comment: I just noticed that the windows partition turned into read-only mode... I'm probably just going to delete it

Comment: "the problem is that it is in the way and there seems to be no way to move it." - The file MFT is likely fragmented.  The answer to the duplicate suggests a tool that can handle MFT fragmentation

Comment: What kind of windows blue screen is it? 0xc000000e?  Some time you have to boot from a windows ISO/usb and use tools like bootrec and maybe /rebuildbcd